# in a function, how to pass a value to an inline sub-function

Tags: kdb

In a function, I'm doing something like this:

```
{3#x} each 7,8,9
/ returns (7 7 7j;8 8 8j;9 9 9j)
```

The following code fails (to my understanding because `N` is not defined in the lambda):

```
foo:{
    N: floor acos -1; 
    {N#x} each x  }
foo 7,8,9
```

My workaround is to use a projection:

```
foo:{
  N: floor acos -1; 
  {y#x}[;N] each x  }
```

Is there a shorter or neater solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem arises due to the lack of what is termed 'lexical scoping' within q/kdb. This essentially means that a local variable is not visible within the body of a local function defined in the same scope. The internal function here cannot 'see' N where you have defined it.

Perhaps a more concise approach would be the following

```
{(floor acos -1)#'x}[7 8 9]
```

Otherwise your workaround works just fine as you are passing in the local variable as an argument. This can be sped up slightly by noticing that you are trying to apply the "take" operator to each of the arguments to it's right therefore you can apply the "each right" operator /:...

```
q)\t:1000000 N:floor acos -1;f:{[N;x] N#/:x};f[N;7 8 9]
1308
q)\t:1000000 N:floor acos -1;{y#x}[;N]each 7 8 9
1835
```

This can be further optimised by using the "each both" operator which will evaluate both arguments of the take operator pair-wise, extending an atom argument to match the length of the list..

This is what is happening in Rahuls example:

```
q)\t:1000000 foo:{#'[floor acos -1;x]};foo 7 8 9
1012
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Inner function does not have access to parent function variables. You need to explicitly pass the required parent variables to the inner function.

In your example, you could avoid inner lambda function by changing your code to use '#' and [each-both](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both):

```
q) foo:{#'[floor acos -1;x]}
q) foo 7 8 9
```

```
7 7 7
8 8 8
9 9 9
```

**Tip:** Always try implementing your logic using KDB operators and adverbs first. They can be combined in number of ways to generate efficient and simple code.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Rahul and Liam, the best approach is a `take` and `each-both` approach for this simple example.

There's also cases where creating a simple projection using parentheses `()` can work while retaining the same legibility. In your example:

```
q){N:floor acos -1;(N#)each x}7 8 9
7 7 7
8 8 8
9 9 9
```

As for variable scoping - the non-global variables are only scoped within the braces `{}` of a function

Comment: Is [this](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#642-operator-projection) what `()` do here?

Comment: Correct, that's it

Answer (score -1):

To avoid having to use lambdas at all, the following solution can be adopted (based on the solution provided above by Liam):

`(#[floor acos -1] @)each 7 8 9`

This format can help obviate the issue of lexical scoping, since it would have access to variable outside of the brackets within the bracket itself. An equivalent statement would be:

`N: floor acos -1; (#[N]@) each 7 8 9`

One can further manipulate the results within the brackets like how one do in a function (since its "functionalised" with the brackets to tell the interpreters on the appropriate sequence of "actions")

`N: floor acos -1; (1_ #[N]@) each 7 8 9`